# Add user information in request

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, nsurlsession

Since `ASIHTTPRequest` is deprecated, I am migrating my code to use `NSURLSession` based server communication. Currently, I am using `NSDictionary` **"userInfo"** property of `ASIHTTPRequest` to send additional user information. The description of **"userInfo"** in `ASIHTTPRequest` documentation is "Custom user information associated with the request (not sent to the server)".
After the request is processed, I re-fetch this **"userInfo"** object from the request object and take action accordingly. 
My `ASIHTTPRequest` code example is

Request:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
[request setDelegate:self];
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"requestCount"];
[request setUserInfo:userInfo];
```

I want to achieve same functionality through NSURLSession, how can I do this?

NSURLSession code example:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: self.queue];

NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:timeOutSeconds];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

                                                           }
                                                       }

                                                   }];

[dataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using completion handler so you can use block variable, try below code:

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: self.queue];

    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:timeOutSeconds];

    __block NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys...........];**

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);

                                                       NSLog(@"UserInfo: %@", userInfo);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

                                                           }
                                                       }

                                                   }];

    [dataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to go is to subclass `NSURLRequest` and add the desired property - be it tag, or userInfo and use it the same way you are used to with `ASIHTTP` framework.